# Extract only 5-digit-number in a string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have an address such that `81000` is the postal code (always a 5-digit-number).

```
address <- "F47, First Floor, PTD 106273, Persiaran Indahpura Utama, Bandar Indahpura, 81000 Kulaijaya, Johor"
```

I am trying to determine the postal code using `regex` and I have tried the following:

```
## postal code pattern
postal_pattern <- '\\d{5}'
## extract postal code
postal_code <- stringr::str_extract_all(address, postal_pattern)
```

However, I got the following output, which is partially correct:

```
> postal_code
[[1]]
[1] "10627" "81000"
```

How can I only extract `81000` using `regex` or any libraries?

Comment: It helps if you provide a list of differently formatted examples to be able to determine how it can be recognized and differentiated from other numbers. For example, if your example had `PTD 12345`, would it be a postal code?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I think Wiktor's solution addressed this issue, since the postal code always appear the last and is always a stand-alone 5-digit (at least for the country's address structure I'm working on).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest extracting the *last* 5-digit number from the string:

```
> str_replace(address, ".*\\b(\\d{5})\\b.*", "\\1")
[1] "81000"
```

Or with base R `sub`:

```
> sub(".*\\b(\\d{5})\\b.*", "\\1", address)
[1] "81000"
```

Since `.*` matches all the string (line) and then starts backtracking to accommodate for the subsequent patterns, and thus the `\d{5}` will match the last 5-digit number (as a whole word).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0 or more chars (other than a line break in the *stringr* version, prepend the pattern with `(?s)` if you need to match line breaks, too), as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `\\b` - a leading word boundary (leading, because the following expected char is a digit)
- `(\\d{5})` -  Group 1: five digits
- `\\b` - a trailing word boundary
- `.*` - the rest of the string (in the *stringr* version, prepend the pattern with `(?s)` if you need to match line breaks, too)

Answer (score 2):

use the regex

```
\\b\\d{5}\\b
```

which would ensure they are at the boundary

Comment: If a 5-digit number appears as a whole word before the code? E.g. `PTD 10627`?

Comment: I didn't get you, it would match 10627

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for an answer in **JavaScript**, here is the solution:

```js
const address = "F47, First Floor, PTD 106273, Persiaran Indahpura Utama, Bandar Indahpura, 81000 Kulaijaya, Johor";
    
const zipCode = address.match(/(\d{5})+/g).at(-1);

console.log(zipCode);

console.log(typeof zipCode);
```

Explanation: The regex above returns the last item from an array of strings. If you have only one item, that's what you will get as an output.